# Ubuntu 22.04 - Laptop does not wake up after sleep

Tags: suspend

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and facing that problem. My laptop does not wake up after suspend and I have to restart it.
My output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i "acpi"`

```
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000009d36e000-0x000000009d36efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ab6ec000-0x00000000ab73bfff] ACPI data
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000ab73c000-0x00000000abef4fff] ACPI NVS
[    0.011496] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.011500] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000000ED2B0 000024 (v02 DELL  )
[    0.011505] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000AB70D0A8 0000D4 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.011512] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000AB72E1D0 00010C (v05 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.011518] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000AB70D210 020FC0 (v02 DELL   CBX3     01072009 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011522] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000ABEF3F80 000040
[    0.011525] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000AB72E2E0 000084 (v03 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.011529] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000AB72E368 000044 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.011532] ACPI: FIDT 0x00000000AB72E3B0 00009C (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.011536] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000AB72E450 00003C (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 MSFT 00000097)
[    0.011539] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000AB72E490 000038 (v01 DELL   CBX3     01072009 AMI. 0005000B)
[    0.011543] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB72E4C8 00050E (v01 SataRe SataTabl 00001000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011546] ACPI: LPIT 0x00000000AB72E9D8 000094 (v01 INTEL  SKL      00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.011550] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB72EA70 000248 (v02 INTEL  sensrhub 00000000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011554] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB72ECB8 002BAE (v02 INTEL  PtidDevc 00001000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011557] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB731868 00094B (v02 INTEL  xh_rvp07 00000000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011561] ACPI: DBGP 0x00000000AB7321B8 000034 (v01 INTEL           00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.011564] ACPI: DBG2 0x00000000AB7321F0 000054 (v00 INTEL           00000000 MSFT 0000005F)
[    0.011568] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB732248 0035DA (v02 SaSsdt SaSsdt   00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011571] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000AB735828 000042 (v01                 00000000      00000000)
[    0.011575] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB735870 000E73 (v02 CpuRef CpuSsdt  00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011578] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000AB7366E8 003BFD (v02 DptfTa DptfTabl 00001000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.011582] ACPI: MSDM 0x00000000AB73A2E8 000055 (v03 DELL   CBX3     06222004 AMI  00010013)
[    0.011585] ACPI: SLIC 0x00000000AB73A340 000176 (v03 DELL   CBX3     01072009 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.011589] ACPI: TCPA 0x00000000AB73A4B8 000032 (v02 ALASKA NAPAASF  00000001 MSFT 01000013)
[    0.011592] ACPI: DMAR 0x00000000AB73A4F0 0000A8 (v01 INTEL  SKL      00000001 INTL 00000001)
[    0.011596] ACPI: ASF! 0x00000000AB73A598 0000A5 (v32 INTEL   HCG     00000001 TFSM 000F4240)
[    0.011599] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xab72e1d0-0xab72e2db]
[    0.011601] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0xab70d210-0xab72e1cf]
[    0.011602] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0xabef3f80-0xabef3fbf]
[    0.011604] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0xab72e2e0-0xab72e363]
[    0.011605] ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0xab72e368-0xab72e3ab]
[    0.011606] ACPI: Reserving FIDT table memory at [mem 0xab72e3b0-0xab72e44b]
[    0.011607] ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0xab72e450-0xab72e48b]
[    0.011609] ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0xab72e490-0xab72e4c7]
[    0.011610] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab72e4c8-0xab72e9d5]
[    0.011611] ACPI: Reserving LPIT table memory at [mem 0xab72e9d8-0xab72ea6b]
[    0.011612] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab72ea70-0xab72ecb7]
[    0.011613] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab72ecb8-0xab731865]
[    0.011615] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab731868-0xab7321b2]
[    0.011616] ACPI: Reserving DBGP table memory at [mem 0xab7321b8-0xab7321eb]
[    0.011617] ACPI: Reserving DBG2 table memory at [mem 0xab7321f0-0xab732243]
[    0.011618] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab732248-0xab735821]
[    0.011619] ACPI: Reserving UEFI table memory at [mem 0xab735828-0xab735869]
[    0.011620] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab735870-0xab7366e2]
[    0.011621] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xab7366e8-0xab73a2e4]
[    0.011622] ACPI: Reserving MSDM table memory at [mem 0xab73a2e8-0xab73a33c]
[    0.011624] ACPI: Reserving SLIC table memory at [mem 0xab73a340-0xab73a4b5]
[    0.011625] ACPI: Reserving TCPA table memory at [mem 0xab73a4b8-0xab73a4e9]
[    0.011626] ACPI: Reserving DMAR table memory at [mem 0xab73a4f0-0xab73a597]
[    0.011627] ACPI: Reserving ASF! table memory at [mem 0xab73a598-0xab73a63c]
[    0.068153] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x1808
[    0.068161] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x01] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.068163] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x02] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.068164] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x03] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.068165] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0x04] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.068194] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.068196] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 high level)
[    0.068201] ACPI: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.068202] ACPI: HPET id: 0x8086a701 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.153048] ACPI: Core revision 20210730
[    0.199023] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x9d36e000-0x9d36efff] (4096 bytes)
[    0.199023] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xab73c000-0xabef4fff] (8097792 bytes)
[    0.201417] ACPI FADT declares the system doesn't support PCIe ASPM, so disable it
[    0.201417] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.201417] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.202695] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.254214] ACPI: 8 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.257462] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.268801] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.268809] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC081020800 0005DC (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Ist  00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.270513] ACPI: \_PR_.CPU0: _OSC native thermal LVT Acked
[    0.272231] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.272238] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC080FD2C00 00037F (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Cst  00003001 INTL 20120913)
[    0.273808] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.273814] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC0811AA6C0 00008E (v02 PmRef  Cpu0Hwp  00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.275212] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.275217] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC0801F8800 000130 (v02 PmRef  HwpLvt   00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.277417] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.277424] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC081024000 0005AA (v02 PmRef  ApIst    00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.279417] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.279422] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC0801F8200 000119 (v02 PmRef  ApHwp    00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.280947] ACPI: Dynamic OEM Table Load:
[    0.280952] ACPI: SSDT 0xFFFF8BC0801F9C00 000119 (v02 PmRef  ApCst    00003000 INTL 20120913)
[    0.284935] ACPI: EC: EC started
[    0.284936] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
[    0.289174] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x934, EC_DATA=0x930
[    0.289177] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV: Boot DSDT EC used to handle transactions
[    0.289179] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.289227] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.289228] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.289275] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.290100] ACPI: Enabled 8 GPEs in block 00 to 7F
[    0.292298] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PG00]
[    0.292952] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PG01]
[    0.293493] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [PG02]
[    0.297846] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.298214] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.298578] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.298942] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.299311] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.300016] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.300387] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.300762] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.302079] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.302441] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.302808] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.303173] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.303535] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.303897] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.304259] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.304622] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.304987] ACPI: PM: Power Resource [WRST]
[    0.328291] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-7e])
[    0.328300] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    0.330450] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug SHPCHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability LTR]
[    0.330452] acpi PNP0A08:00: FADT indicates ASPM is unsupported, using BIOS configuration
[    0.345982] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKA configured for IRQ 11
[    0.346057] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKB configured for IRQ 10
[    0.346131] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKC configured for IRQ 11
[    0.346203] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKD configured for IRQ 11
[    0.346275] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKE configured for IRQ 11
[    0.346346] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKF configured for IRQ 11
[    0.346418] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKG configured for IRQ 11
[    0.346490] ACPI: PCI: Interrupt link LNKH configured for IRQ 11
[    0.348683] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
[    0.348685] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
[    0.348695] ACPI: EC: EC_CMD/EC_SC=0x934, EC_DATA=0x930
[    0.348697] ACPI: EC: GPE=0x14
[    0.348699] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV: Boot DSDT EC initialization complete
[    0.348701] ACPI: \_SB_.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV: EC: Used to handle transactions and events
[    0.348782] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    0.349439] PCI: Using ACPI for IRQ routing
[    0.375458] pnp: PnP ACPI init
[    0.382784] pnp: PnP ACPI: found 12 devices
[    0.388542] clocksource: acpi_pm: mask: 0xffffff max_cycles: 0xffffff, max_idle_ns: 2085701024 ns
[    0.410050] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.LPCB.HEC.CHRG], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210730/psargs-330)
[    0.410069] ACPI Error: Aborting method \PNOT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.410077] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.AC._PSR due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210730/psparse-529)
[    0.410086] ACPI: \_SB_.AC__: Error reading AC Adapter state: AE_NOT_FOUND
[    0.410187] ACPI: button: Lid Switch [LID0]
[    0.410240] ACPI: button: Power Button [PBTN]
[    0.410282] ACPI: button: Sleep Button [SBTN]
[    0.410333] ACPI: button: Power Button [PWRF]
[    0.412812] ACPI: thermal: Thermal Zone [THM] (25 C)
[    0.485733] ACPI: battery: Slot [BAT0] (battery present)
[    0.763446] acpi LNXPOWER:03: hash matches
[    2.863827] parport_pc 00:06: reported by Plug and Play ACPI
[    3.780702] ACPI: video: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
```

Comment: Before anything else, update UEFI. Then also check its settings as many require some changes in order to work properly with non-Windows OSes.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i "acpi"`

Comment: @Raffa its says grep: i: No such file or directory
grep: acpi: No such file or directory

Comment: `-i` not `i` ... copy and paste this ---> `sudo dmesg | grep -i "acpi"`

Comment: @Raffa Sorry that was my bad,but now it generated a very length text, how can I add screenshot of it

Comment: no screenshot please ... copy and paste instead

Comment: @Raffa I added, Please check

Comment: Nooooooooooooooooooo

Comment: :) one o is enough ... just like ---> *no* ... The issue you're having is the same as the linked post above. Check the logs in that post and compare them to yours ... if you know otherwise, please add the information you know to your question ... that would help clarify more.

Comment: @nobody no I tried almost everything and now gave up

Comment: Please try Boot option `pci=nocrs`

Comment: @ChAtif Did you ever solve the problem? I have a similar issue and nothing that I have tried seems to work

Comment: @martin36 unfortunately not, I've been shifted to macOS now